# Switching Desktops Causes Gimp to not see the Uc-Logic Tablet

Tags: tablet, gimp

The tablet (uc-logic athene M) works fine with gimp after choosing the "screen" option from "input devices". But if I switch to another desktop and come back to gimp, I can no longer draw anything on the canvas.

I can move the cursor around and click menus but I just can't click on the canvas. (it's also what happens if I don't select the screen option from input devices settings)

The problem continues after installing digimend driver.

Maybe I should also mention that this happens only with gimp. There's no problem at all with krita.

Comment: Does the same happen for other GTK+-based apps that have something like a canvas?

Comment: nope. I've seen this problem only with gimp. (tried, mypaint, krita and inkscape)

Comment: You should file a bug report in the Ubuntu bug tracker. They can report it to the correct upstream once it has been determined what exactly is causing it.

Comment: logging out and and logging back in solves the problem for some reason.  It means every time I restart my pc I also have to relog.

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a solution. Please report the bug to Ubuntu, it is important that those are filed by the affected users who can provide additional information if necessary.